# LibreOffice 7.0.1 broken installation

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04, dpkg, libreoffice

I have downloaded the recent version ( 7.0.1) of LibreOffice. The problem is when I am trying to install, it is not installing properly.

How I am installing it?

I have extracted the LibreOffice installer ZIP file, enter in the `DEBS` folder, and executing all packages by using the following command `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

After running the command it encounters some following errors

```
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: <decompress> subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive libobasis7.0-core_7.0.1.2-2_amd64.deb (--install):
cannot copy extracted data for './opt/libreoffice7.0/program/libbiblo.so' to '/opt/libreoffice7.0/program/libbiblo.so.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
```

Same `dpkg` error for the other packages too like calc, draw

```
dpkg: error processing package libobasis7.0-base (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libobasis7.0-calc:
libobasis7.0-calc depends on libobasis7.0-core (>= 7.0.1.2); however:
Package libobasis7.0-core is not installed.
libobasis7.0-calc depends on libobasis7.0-core (<= 7.0.1.2-2); however:
Package libobasis7.0-core is not installed.
```

At last it shows

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libobasis7.0-core_7.0.1.2-2_amd64.deb
 libobasis7.0-base
 libobasis7.0-calc
 libobasis7.0-draw
 libobasis7.0-en-us
 libobasis7.0-extension-beanshell-script-provider
 libobasis7.0-extension-javascript-script-provider
 libobasis7.0-extension-mediawiki-publisher
 libobasis7.0-extension-nlpsolver
 libobasis7.0-extension-pdf-import
 libobasis7.0-extension-report-builder
 libobasis7.0-firebird
 libobasis7.0-gnome-integration
 libobasis7.0-graphicfilter
 libobasis7.0-images
 libobasis7.0-impress
 libobasis7.0-kde-integration
 libobasis7.0-libreofficekit-data
 libobasis7.0-math
 libobasis7.0-ogltrans
 libobasis7.0-onlineupdate
 libobasis7.0-ooolinguistic
 libobasis7.0-postgresql-sdbc
 libobasis7.0-python-script-provider
 libobasis7.0-pyuno
 libobasis7.0-writer
 libobasis7.0-xsltfilter
 libreoffice7.0
 libreoffice7.0-base
 libreoffice7.0-calc
 libreoffice7.0-dict-en
 libreoffice7.0-dict-es
 libreoffice7.0-dict-fr
 libreoffice7.0-draw
 libreoffice7.0-en-us
 libreoffice7.0-impress
 libreoffice7.0-math
 libreoffice7.0-writer
 libobasis7.0-librelogo
```

I can see the LibreOffice entries in the menu item, but unable to launch them

Now, when I am trying to uninstall them, ( `sudo apt-get purge libreoffice-core` )  I am getting the following error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libobasis7.0-base : Depends: libobasis7.0-core (>= 7.0.1.2) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libobasis7.0-core (<= 7.0.1.2-2) but it is not installable
 libobasis7.0-calc : Depends: libobasis7.0-core (>= 7.0.1.2) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libobasis7.0-core (<= 7.0.1.2-2) but it is not installable
 libobasis7.0-draw : Depends: libobasis7.0-core (>= 7.0.1.2) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libobasis7.0-core (<= 7.0.1.2-2) but it is not installable
 libobasis7.0-en-us : Depends: libobasis7.0-core (>= 7.0.1.2) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libobasis7.0-core (<= 7.0.1.2-2) but it is not installable
 libobasis7.0-extension-beanshell-script-provider : Depends: libobasis7.0-core (>= 7.0.1.2) but it is not installable
```

How can I fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The question is, apparently, unrelated to Ubuntu, but you are more then welcome to search this site for "howto remove broken packages".

Comment: @guiverc  It's Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Download the LibreOffice packages again, suppose they are downloaded at ~ / Downloads.

https://ftp.nluug.nl/office/libreoffice/libreoffice/stable/7.0.1/deb/x86_64/LibreOffice_7.0.1_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz

https://ftp.nluug.nl/office/libreoffice/libreoffice/stable/7.0.1/deb/x86_64/LibreOffice_7.0.1_Linux_x86-64_deb_helppack_en-GB.tar.gz

https://ftp.nluug.nl/office/libreoffice/libreoffice/stable/7.0.1/deb/x86_64/LibreOffice_7.0.1_Linux_x86-64_deb_langpack_en-GB.tar.gz

Then run in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get -f install

sudo apt remove --purge libreoffice*

sudo apt remove --purge libobasis*

sudo apt autoremove

cd ~/Downloads

for x in *.tar.gz; do tar xfv $x; done

sudo dpkg -i LibreOffice_*/DEBS/*.deb
```

Comment: I would add that they should run `sha256sum /path/to/LibreOffice_7.0.1_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz` and ensure it matches ["a3823053e4b0e7b02c3a8b1f582b447ef86ef6084f1777dc3ae7d18395ce598b"](https://download.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/stable/7.0.1/deb/x86_64/LibreOffice_7.0.1_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz.mirrorlist)

Comment: Great solution. It works!  Thank You.

Comment: @kyodake One minor thing, for me, sudo apt remove --purge libreoffice* is not working first place, so I used sudo apt-get -f install and then sudo apt remove --purge libreoffice*  after that everything works perfectly.

Comment: @kyodake I tried to edit the answer & add sudo apt-get -f install, but it got rejected. It would be great if you edit the answer & add this command too.

Comment: @ Mir Rahed Uddin: Done

Comment: @kyodake Thank you, very much sir :)

Comment: `sudo apt remove --purge libreoffice*` outputs `E: Unable to locate package libreoffice*`. Looks `*` is not supported by `apt` on my ubuntu20.04?

Answer (score 3):

You have chosen very difficult method. It is unnecessary.

“LibreOffice Packaging” team have [a PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Elibreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/libreoffice-7-0), to install LibO 7.0 packages use:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-7-0
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet is to use the snap version of LibreOffice.  I had the same problem as you and after I had deleted the deb version, I installed the current snap version which at the time was 4.6.2.  It has now updated to 7.0.1.  It works pretty well but I don't know if the icons are right.