# Adding Help file to PPA installed LibreOffice 7.0?

Tags: apt, package-management, libreoffice, ppa

How about a way to install the LO associated help file that is a separate downloaded DEB?

N0rbert's suggestion for the main package of LO worked for me, use the PPA (see below):
But what will work to install the help file for LibreOffice?
LibreOffice_7.0.1_Linux_x86-64_deb_helppack_en-US.tar.gz
It's extracted DEB generates a similar dependency missing message.

[N0rbert wrote](https://askubuntu.com/a/1273240/124466):

> You have chosen very difficult method. It is unnecessary.

> “LibreOffice Packaging” team have a PPA, to install LibO 7.0 packages use:
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-7-0
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install libreoffice
> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

answered Sep 7 at 8:50
N0rbert

I hope someone knows the solution or workaround for the associated help file.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt install libreoffice-help-en-us`?

Comment: Simply do not mix packages from different sources. Use help packages from [LO PPA](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/libreoffice-7-0/+packages), they are named `libreoffice-help-<lang>`.

Answer (score 5):

Just install it from the PPA itself: the package is called `libreoffice-help-`*`<language code>`*

Comment: Thanks. Was a big help: not just a solution but how to do better....