# LibreOffice 7.0 offline help missing dependencies

Tags: software-installation, libreoffice

I just installed LibreOffice 7.0.3. I downloaded the offline help, but it won't install because of unsatisfied dependencies. Gdebi reports that it wants "libobasis7.0-en-us >= 7.0.3.1". How do I install that?

Using Ubuntu 20.10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LibreOffice 7.0.1 broken installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273156/libreoffice-7-0-1-broken-installation)

Comment: Kulfy - No, I saw that earlier and it didn't help. Thanks.

Comment: Blair, as a suggestion, it is a nice idea to put what you have already tried or researched in the question when posting it. This avoids other users to undergo useless search work.

Comment: Sorry, Quasimodo. I don't spend much time here.

Comment: Sorry, Quasimodo. I'm unfamiliar with the protocols here so I don't know what is expected. As implied in the question, I used gdebi to try to install the help file, and it responded: 

Error: Dependency not satisfiable: libobasis7.0-en-us (>=7.0.3.1)

I tried to install it using apt-get (probably incorrectly) , with no luck. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing the missing dependencies using

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Unfortunately libobasis7.0-en-us is [not available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libobasis7.0-en-us&searchon=names&suite=groovy&section=all) in official Ubuntu repositories. So, the mentioned command would hardly make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add libreoffice PPA [instead](https://launchpad.net/%7Elibreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=groovy) with commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice libreoffice-help-en-us
```

to get latest LibO 7.0.3.